# How do you find the probability of a certain state in Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, computer-science, markov-chains, queueing-theory

This question appears without answer in an old exam I found (not a homework question)

> Suppose messages that enter a system need to be processed by two
>   servers. They arrive at the system at a rate of `a` and queue up to be
>   processed by `Server1`. `Server1` processes the messages at a rate of
>   `u1`. Then they proceed to `Server2` where they queue up until they
>   are served, at a rate of `u2`. The queues can be infinite.
>
> What is the probability that there will be `k` messages in `Server1`'s
>   queue?

I'm confused about how exactly to go about this. There are an infinite number of ways to have some given quantity of messages in the queue. Somehow I have to reconcile the amount of cases each multiplied by their probability, which I am also unsure of how to get to exactly.

I drew a Markov diagram to help me a little:

[image: Markov Chain]

Answer (score 1):

One can forget Server 2. The length of the queue at Server 1 increases by $1$ at rate $a$ and, when positive, it decreases by one at rate $u_1$. This is the most classical birth-and-death chain, whose stationary distribution exists if and only if $a\lt u_1$ and can be readily found, either reading your textbook or solving the associated system of linear equations.

Comment: But the question is, what is the probability of there being `k` messages in `Server1`'s queue?

Comment: Yes, and the only sensible answer to this question is $\pi(k)$ where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of the length of Server 1's queue. Hence my post.